# Swift FireStore Listener throws error when loading application the second time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, listener, google-cloud-firestore

Hi I am in desperate need for some help

*All this is happening in a UIViewController child class*

I am currently attaching the listener and populating an array and then feeding it to a UICollectionView in the following function (excuse some of the cut off code):

```
    fileprivate func fetchNotes() { // This function is called in vidDidLoad()
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
  // Attaching listener (ie. listener is an attribute of the class)
    listener = db.collection("Courses").document(titleForNavBar).collection("Notes")
        .addSnapshotListener { snapshot, error in
        // checking for any error
        if error != nil {
            self.arrayOfNotes.removeAll()
            self.allNotesView.arrayOfNotes = self.arrayOfNotes
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.allNotesView.allNotesCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
            return
        } else {
            self.arrayOfNotes.removeAll()
            // if there is no error, the array holding all the objects is populated, in a for..loop
            for document in (snapshot?.documents)! {
            if let noteName = document.data()["noteName"] as? String,
               let lectureInformation = document.data()["lectureInformation"] as? String,
               let noteDescription = document.data()["noteDescription"] as? String,
               let forCourse = document.data()["forCourse"] as? String,
                    let storageReference = document.data()["storageReference"] as? String,
               let noteSize = document.data()["noteSize"] as? Int,
               let rating = document.data()["rating"] as? Int
                {
                    self.arrayOfNotes.append(Note(forCourse: forCourse, lectureInformation: lectureInformation, noteDescription: noteDescription, noteName: noteName, noteSize: noteSize, rating: rating, storageReference: storageReference))
                    self.allNotesView.arrayOfNotes = self.arrayOfNotes
                    // reloading the UICollectionView (on the main thread) so that it displays new data
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.allNotesView.allNotesCollectionView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

When the view disappears, I am also removing the listener

```
override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidDisappear(true)
    if listener != nil {
    listener.remove()
    }
    print("listener removed")
}
```

This works fine, when I install the application for the first time on any device or simulator. When I try to launch the controller, the second time, I get a very nasty error that I have no idea how to debug.

To be accurate the console throws this error:

> NoteShare[97230:10528984] *** Assertion failure in -[FSTLevelDBRemoteDocumentCache decodedMaybeDocument:withKey:], third_party/firebase/ios/Source/Firestore/Source/Local/FSTLevelDBRemoteDocumentCache.mm:152

I know this question is quite long (sorry about that), but have you guys come across this error. Please give some hint on how to solve this problem. Thanks! If you need to see any other piece of my code, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be failing [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/793672432249b6f60667af72ef6594acaa93fe7c/Firestore/Source/Local/FSTLevelDBRemoteDocumentCache.mm#L150). I don't see what you could be doing wrong in your code to cause that, so you may have hit a bug. It seems very similar to [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/445), which has been fixed in the repo but not been released.